# Como mostrar nome sessão do usuário dentro de msg com toastr usando Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

Projeto é em PHP 7 com laravel 5.8 usando toastr para notificações, existe a possibilidade de colocar na exibição da msg toastr info(exemplo) o nome da sessão do usuário?

usando a sessão:

`Auth::user()->name`

Minha controller user:

```
      public function index()
{
    toastr()->success("Você está logado","{!! Auth::user()->name !!}");
    return view('home')->with('$user',Auth::user();
}
```

Comment: Não seria mais simples concatenar o valor? `"Seja bem-vindo, " . Auth::user()->name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta concatenar o valor no parametro do metodo `success`

```
toastr()->success("Você está logado " . Auth::user()->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, levando em conta que você esta utilizando o padrão MVC, a forma simples é utilizar as diretivas do BLADE para exibir seus dados diretamente na view.

**view('home') -> with( '$user' , Auth::user()) ;**

Aqui você ja passa para a view o valor indicado, neste caso você trata este valor na view.

Mas este processo pode ser realizado de varias formas, eu acredito que devemos separar o máximo as obrigações de back-end e front-end.